# Layered window size bigger than the size of the contents

Tags: c++, winapi, layered-windows

I want to create a layered window, the size of which is bigger than the size of its contents (hdcSrc). So that the window is for example 900x900, and we can place a 300x300 image inside of it anywhere we want, while the rest of the window is transparent.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment( lib, "Gdiplus.lib" )

HWND hwnd;

int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

void updateTestWindow();

LRESULT CALLBACK windowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PSTR, INT iCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;

    // GDI+ elements
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;

    // Initialize GDI+.
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    // Register Window Class

    WNDCLASS testWindowClass;

    testWindowClass.lpszClassName = TEXT("TestWindow");
    testWindowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    testWindowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    testWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = windowProcedure;
    testWindowClass.hIcon = 0;
    testWindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    testWindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    testWindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    testWindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    testWindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;

    RegisterClass(&testWindowClass);

    // Create a layered window

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_LAYERED,
        TEXT("TestWindow"), // window class name
        TEXT("TestWindow"), // window caption
        WS_POPUP,           // window style
        0,      // initial x position
        0,      // initial y position
        screenWidth,                    // initial x size
        screenHeight,                   // initial y size
        NULL,               // parent window handle
        NULL,               // window menu handle
        hInstance,          // program instance handle
        NULL);              // creation parameters

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);

    
    // Update the layered window using a custom function
    updateTestWindow();




    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}


void updateTestWindow()
{
    // Let's imagine that in reality we are drawing an image, but to test it, just draw a rectangle
    int imageWidth = 300;
    int imageHeight = 300;

    HDC screenDC = GetDC(NULL);

    // Create a DC for drawing
    HDC drawingDC = CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);

    // Create a new bitmap for drawing on it
    HBITMAP newBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(screenDC, imageWidth, imageHeight);

    // Select the new bitmap to draw on it and save the old one
    HBITMAP oldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(drawingDC, newBitmap);

    // Create graphics object
    Graphics graphics(drawingDC);

    // Draw a rectangle
    Pen redPen(Color(255, 255, 0, 0), 15);
    Rect windowRect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageWidth);
    graphics.DrawRectangle(&redPen, windowRect);

    // The position of the layered window
    POINT windowPosition = { 0, 0 };
    
    // The size of the layered window   
    SIZE windowSize = { imageWidth, imageHeight };    // <----------------------------------!!!!

    POINT drawingDCPosition = { 0,0 };

    // Create a blend function
    BLENDFUNCTION blend = { 0 };
    blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    // Call UpdateLayeredWindow
    UpdateLayeredWindow(hwnd, screenDC, &windowPosition, &windowSize,
        drawingDC, &drawingDCPosition, 0, &blend, ULW_ALPHA);

    // Clean up
    SelectObject(drawingDC, oldBitmap);
    DeleteObject(newBitmap);
    DeleteDC(drawingDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, screenDC);
}
```

This creates a window that is exactly the size of the image that's drawn on it.
We can reduce the window size: `SIZE windowSize = { imageWidth-100, imageHeight-100 };` and the window will be drawn as expected - smaller size, while the image is the same size but now it's clipped (in this case, the rectangle is clipped).

However, if we want to achieve what I described in the beginning, `SIZE windowSize = { imageWidth+100, imageHeight+100 };` doesn't work. The window is just not rendered at all, yet it opens (window taskbar icon is visible).

I probably just can't understand how a layered window works completely yet, which is why I can't understand why in this example it's not being rendered.

**Is it possible to create such a layered window at all?** And if yes, then how?

Or maybe this is not something I should be doing at all?

Just as a note: The reason I want to do this, is to use the layered window as a sort of an overlay, that would constantly be the size of the screen but the images, figures and text would be drawn on to it, updated, moved and so on.

Comment: Layered windows need to be updated from a bitmap the same size as the window.

Comment: You cannot create such a layered window, and for best drawing performance by the layered window and any underlying windows, the layered window should be as small as possible.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Your answer seems to be correct. It helped me remember that there is also the size of the bitmap that is important. I changed the ```CreateCompatibleBitmap()``` function to use the size I want (screen size) and it worked. So thank you!
Post it as the answer if you want, and I will accept it as correct, or if you don't want to, I will post an answer myself :)

Comment: @SongZhu Thank you for the info. It's actually possible to create it, I managed it thanks to Jonathan's answer, but I do wonder how big of an influence such usage of layered window has on the performance, you are probably right in that it is best to use the smallest size possible and perhaps this should be included as an important note in the answer